# Catch external HXR and Javascript errors from the console

Tags: javascript

I am building a small tool for a no-code platform that I wish can send all the errors from the front-end to a server.
Here's the code I wrote so far to get the errors during run-time:

```
// In this function I want to catch XHR (APIs) errors and other general errors
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    window.onerror = function (msg, source, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
    report_error_bhelper(msg, "onerror")
    }
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
      cache: false,
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
      var msg = jqXHR + exception
      report_error_bhelper(msg, "XHR")
      }
  });
});

// In this function I catch all "error" and "warn" console logs
(function() {
    var exError = console.error;
    var exWarn = console.warn;
    console.error = function(msg) {
        exError.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('Error detected, loggin error to Bubble Helper...')
        report_error_bhelper(msg, "error")
    }
        console.warn = function(msg) {
        exWarn.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('Warning detected, loggin error to Bubble Helper...')
        report_error_bhelper(msg, "warn")
    }
})()
```

The second part of the code works really well and I got all my errors sent, but I am not able to catch other errors, especially when HXR requests fails.

I am missing something? I would love some tips!

I've tried implementing the "window.onerror" at different level (when DOM is loaded, raw in the code, ...) but it seems like I won't get the errors

Comment: `ajaxSetup` only sets up a *default* `error` handler afaik, so it would be overwritten if in the actual call you pass a different one

Comment: _"HXR"_ did you mean XHR as in XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Bergi Do I need to remove the `error: function(jqXHR, exception) {` then ?

Comment: @VictorNihoul No. I'm just saying it might not always work.

Comment: @phuzi Yes! I am trying to catch errors from API requests, like the following `POST https://xrrz-kotr-zdpv.f2.xano.io/api:qc3Gb5sR/report_error 500 ` `GET https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`